# CLIPS & clipsmm: slot of float type

Tags: c++, clips

I have a problem with slot of float type. There is a template in my knowledge-base file:

```
(deftemplate test
(slot slot1 (type INTEGER) (default 10))
(slot slot2 (type FLOAT) (default 4.0))
)
```

I use clipsmm for integration CLIPS with Qt-application. I assert fact this way:

```
CLIPS::Fact::pointer fact;
QString fact_str = "(test (slot1 15) (slot2 4.3))";
fact = env.assert_fact(Std(fact_str)); //Std() translates QString into std::string
```

This fact is added to agenda, but slot2 has value = 4.0 instead 4.3:

```
<== Activation 0 start:
<== f-0 (initial-fact)
:== ?answer ==> 0 <== 0 //this is global
==> Activation 0 start:
==> f-0 (initial-fact)
Start!
==> f-1 (test (slot1 15) (slot2 4.0))
```

If I use "XCLIPS Expert System" all is good and slot2 has value = 4.3. What do I do wrong?

UPD. I changed the environment.cpp this way:

```
Fact::pointer Environment::assert_fact( const std::string& factstring )
{
  void* clips_fact = EnvAssertString( m_cobj, const_cast<char*>(factstring.c_str()) );

  std::cout << "factstring =" << factstring << std::endl;     //std::cout is added
  if ( clips_fact )
    return Fact::create( *this, clips_fact );
  else
    return Fact::pointer();
}
```

and it is displayed correctly:
"factstring = (test (slot1 15) (slot2 4.3))"

UPD2. I tried to add fact this way:

```
CLIPS::Template::pointer temp;
temp = env.get_template(Std("test"));
CLIPS::Fact::pointer f1;
f1 = CLIPS::Fact::create(env, temp);
CLIPS::Value v1 = CLIPS::Value(15);
CLIPS::Value v2 = CLIPS::Value(4.3);
f1->set_slot(Std("slot1"), v1);
f1->set_slot(Std("slot2"), v2);
env.assert_fact(f1);
```

and got such result:

```
==> f-2     (test (slot1 15) (slot2 4,3.0))
```

Comment: I work in Linux (OpenSuse 13.2), use CLIPS 6.30.0-2.6, clipsmm-0.3.4, Qt 4.8.6

Comment: Have you verified in the clipsmm assert_fact method in environment.cpp that the converted string passed to EnvAssertString is valid?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. It seems to be all right with the converted string.

Comment: You want to check the value of factstring.c_str() as well to verify that that conversion works. If it works with the standard clips executable but not with clipsmm, perhaps there's some difference in the compilation options being used.

Comment: I checked the value of  factstring.c_str(): it is right too. Please tell me which compilation options you mean and where to look at them?

Comment: I updated the question again (upd2). It is unclear what happens with the translation from string to float.

Comment: I can't specifically tell you what to look for because I don't specifically know how you constructed the executables you're using. If you've got two executables and one works and the other doesn't, you need to look for what's different between the two. If there are no differences in the code or the way the executables are built, you should step through the code using a debugger to see where the two differ in execution.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried to compare the compilation options, but didn't get any result. Helped to change the locale settings. If somebody knows more neat solution, please, write it here.

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite figure it out, but the following helped: change the number formatting in the locale settings of the operating system. By default "ru_Ru" was used, in which "," is used to separate decimal places. I changed it to "ba_Ru" (only for "Detailed settings-> Numbers"), and values of float type became correct in my expert system. But now I have some problems with opening files, which include cyrillic. I had to rename some folders and files.